# how to get rid of a for loop in pytorch / numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

this is a typical question though I have no clue to solve it. Let
`timesteps = [12, 5, 6, 7]` or one dimensional vector. Let be `noise` a matrice of the shape `[5, 1, 1, 28]`. I want to create matrices of the shape `[1, 1, 28]` with the values of `timesteps`, so e.g. `12 * torch.ones([1, 1, 28])`. At last I concated them.  I've created this code

```
for scalar in range(int(timesteps.shape[0])):
    list_mask.append(
        scalar * torch.ones((1, *noise.shape[1:]))
    )

mask = torch.cat(list_mask)
```

Do you have any clue how to not use a loop but get the same results?

Answer (score 1):

With only four timesteps, I assume noise is actually 4x1x1x28. With broadcasting, you can multiply a ones array of shape 4x1x1x28 with a reshaped timesteps as a 4x1x1x1 array. Broadcasting will repeat the timestep along the latter three axes.

```
noise = np.ones((4, 1, 1, 28))*np.array(timesteps)[:, None, None, None]
```